# How to visible picklist field on the selction of lookup record

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created 1 Form in lwc but  have some criteria where I click on the lookup field and on the selection of lookup record data then and only the particular picklist field will be visible and no impact on other field

Comment: please provide a source code of your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<template>` tags to display HTML code conditionally.

```js
<template if:true={isVisible}>
  <div>
     Content
  </div>
</template>
```

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_conditional)